# React - changing order of components from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React component `List` that contains an array of `ListItem` components that it renders.  The `ListItems` are preceded by a `ListHeader` component that, when clicked, should sort the `ListItems` underneath it.  I'm trying to make a simple sorting function to re-render the `ListItems` in the desired order.

Here is the component:

```js
class List extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: this.props.items,
    }
  }

  doSort(col) {
    let sortAsc = this.state.sortCol == col ? !this.state.sortCol : true;
    let sorted = this.state.items.slice().sort((a, b) => {
      if(a.attributes[col] < b.attributes[col]) {
        return sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
      } else if(a.attributes[col] > b.attributes[col]) {
        return sortAsc ? -1 : 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      items: sorted,
      sortCol: col,
      sortAsc: sortAsc
    });
  }

  render() {
    let items = this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
      return <ListItem item={item} key={index} />
    });

    return(
      <div>
        <ListHeader item={this.state.items[0]} handleSort={this.doSort.bind(this)} />
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

When `doSort` is called, it sorts the components in the list and sets `this.state.items` to the new, sorted array.  According to the debugger, this is being done correctly, and `render()` is being called afterward.  However the order of the components as rendered on the page is not changing.

Any ideas why setting the state with a sorted array is not changing the order in which referenced components are being rendered?

Comment: They keys don't change; try using something like `item.id` as `key`, as opposed to the `index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using the index as key as it is considered anti-pattern.

More on the same can be read here. https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: That did it - setting the key to `item.id` fixed it.  In hindsight that makes a lot of sense.  Thank you!